# Reflect dropdown balances to another sheet

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to ask if it is possible to reflect the values of running balance to account balances in another sheet?

The value was reflected in ledger using drop down list, and if it is possible, to reflect the running balance to another sheet.

I've tried to use some function but its not working. It is possible to reflect value, but whenever I change the name from drop down it also changes.

Please see the attached picture.

The thing is, I put the value manually in the second picture the running balance from the first picture. Is it possible that whenever the running balance would change, or the name from drop down list would change, or is it possible to automatically put value on the second picture, from the running balance of first picture?

Take note: The first picture is a drop down list with different account titles. The second picture is an account balances of all account titles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the first image, where are those line items coming from. Are they pulled from the general ledger with a regular spreadsheet formula like `QUERY() ` or nested `IF() ` statements? Or is there a script running in the background?  I ask, because depending on how your data is set up, you may be able to run a query formula in the cell of the second image instead of using a script.

Comment: Hi! Already solved the problem. Thank you!

But, no, there is no script running in the background. Just formulas.

Comment: Can you tell us what your solution is?  Just curious.

Comment: @Kris something like this
=IF(A4:A="","",ABS( SUMIF('General Journal'!B$5:B,A4,'General Journal'!D$5:D) 
                  - SUMIF('General Journal'!B$5:B,A4,'General Journal'!E$5:E)))